# Facebook Captcha

Tags: facebook, http, request, captcha

I'm trying to get the facebook captcha image in c# and then display it in my app and send the response back to facebook. My app works fine which basically communicates with facebook but after a while it asks for captcha. I incorporated the functionality for entering the captcha and when I send it to facebook using webclient I get the response that it worked. But when I again try to query the data I'm again directed to the captcha link and the cycle continues.

I just can't figure out how I attach the information in my subsequent requests that I have already entered captcha or what information returned from the captcha response header I should attach to my new requests.

Sorry for my poor English. I hope I conveyed the message.

```
    private bool checkNumber(string number)
    {
        int index = 0;
        StreamReader streamReader;
        NameValueCollection nameValuePairs = new NameValueCollection();
        nameValuePairs.Add("lsd", "AVoA7hUw");
        nameValuePairs.Add("email", number);
        nameValuePairs.Add("did_submit", "Search");
        nameValuePairs.Add("__user", "0");
        nameValuePairs.Add("__a", "1");
        nameValuePairs.Add("__dyn", "7w");
        nameValuePairs.Add("__req", "1");
        nameValuePairs.Add("fb_dtsg", "AQCHtLfI");
        nameValuePairs.Add("phstamp", "1658167721167610273109");


        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        byte[] response = client.UploadValues("https://www.facebook.com/ajax/login/help/identify.php?ctx=recover", nameValuePairs);
        char[] chars = new char[response.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = Convert.ToChar(response[i]);
        }
        string s = new string(chars);
        if (s.Contains("onload"))
        {
            String coo = "";

            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            String[] cookieString = client.ResponseHeaders.Get("set-cookie").Split(';');

            string name = cookieString[0].Substring(0, cookieString[0].IndexOf("=")).TrimStart();
            string value = cookieString[0].Substring(cookieString[0].IndexOf("=") + 1).TrimEnd(';');
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
            cookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";
            cookies.Add(cookie);
            coo += name + "=" + value + ";";

            Cookie newCookie = new Cookie("reg_fb_gate", "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F");
            newCookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";
            cookies.Add(newCookie);
            newCookie = new Cookie("reg_fb_ref", "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin%2Fidentify%3Fctx%3Drecover");
            newCookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";

            coo += "reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F;reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin%2Fidentify%3Fctx%3Drecover;";
            cookies.Add(newCookie);

            name = cookieString[4].Substring(10, cookieString[4].LastIndexOf("=") - 10).TrimStart();
            value = cookieString[4].Substring(cookieString[4].IndexOf("=") + 1).TrimEnd(';');
            cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
            cookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";
            cookies.Add(cookie);
            coo += name + "=" + value + ";";






            s = "";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate");

            //req.Headers.Add("set-cookie", cookie);
            req.Host = "www.facebook.com";
            req.CookieContainer = cookies;
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0";
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            streamReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            s = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            if (s.Contains("sometext"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            while (s.Contains("captcha") || index == -1)
            {
                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate");
                req.Host = "www.facebook.com";
                req.CookieContainer = cookies;
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0";
                req.KeepAlive = true;
                resp = req.GetResponse();
                streamReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                s = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();

                checkBox1.IsChecked = false;

                index = s.IndexOf("https://www.facebook.com/captcha/tfbimage.php?");
                if (index == -1)
                    continue;
                string uri = s.Substring(index);
                uri = uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("\\\"") - 1);

                string captcha_persist_data = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("captcha_persist_data"));
                captcha_persist_data = captcha_persist_data.Substring(s.IndexOf("value=\\\"") + 7);
                captcha_persist_data = captcha_persist_data.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("\\\"") - 1);
                client = new WebClient();
                coo += "wd=1920x976;act=1374854201395/3;_e_0oL1_0=%5B%220oL1%22%2C1375031079666%2C%22act%22%2C1375031079665%2C0%2C%22captcha_response%22%2C%22click%22%2C%22click%22%2C%22-%22%2C%22r%22%2C%22%2Frecover%2Finitiate%22%2C%7B%22ft%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22gt%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1903%2C16%5D;_e_0oL1_1=%5B%220oL1%22%2C1375031092251%2C%22act%22%2C1375031092250%2C1%2C%22captcha_submit%22%2C%22click%22%2C%22click%22%2C%22-%22%2C%22r%22%2C%22%2Frecover%2Finitiate%22%2C%7B%22ft%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22gt%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1903%2C16%5D";
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0");
                client.Headers.Add("host", "www.facebook.com");
                client.Headers.Add("set-cookie", coo);                    

                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
                MessageBox.Show("Alert");
                streamReader = new StreamReader("D:\\abc.txt");
                string newStr = streamReader.ReadLine();
                streamReader.Close();



                nameValuePairs = new NameValueCollection();
                nameValuePairs.Add("lsd", "AVoA7hUw");
                /*nameValuePairs.Add("email", number);
                nameValuePairs.Add("did_submit", "Search");
                nameValuePairs.Add("__user", "0");
                nameValuePairs.Add("__a", "1");
                nameValuePairs.Add("__dyn", "7w");
                nameValuePairs.Add("__req", "1");
                nameValuePairs.Add("fb_dtsg", "AQCHtLfI");
                nameValuePairs.Add("ttstamp", "26581656790668586");  */
                nameValuePairs.Add("captcha_persist_data", captcha_persist_data);
                //nameValuePairs.Add("recaptcha_challenge_field", "");                  

                nameValuePairs.Add("captcha_response", newStr);
                //nameValuePairs.Add("confirmed", "1");
                nameValuePairs.Add("captcha_submit", "Submit");

                response = client.UploadValues("https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate", nameValuePairs);
                chars = new char[response.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
                {
                    chars[i] = Convert.ToChar(response[i]);
                }
                s = new string(chars);

                cookies = new CookieContainer();

                coo = "";                    
                cookieString = client.ResponseHeaders.Get("set-cookie").Split(';');

                name = cookieString[0].Substring(0, cookieString[0].IndexOf("=")).TrimStart();
                value = cookieString[0].Substring(cookieString[0].IndexOf("=") + 1).TrimEnd(';');
                cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
                cookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";
                cookies.Add(cookie);
                coo += name + "=" + value + ";";

                newCookie = new Cookie("reg_fb_gate", "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F");
                newCookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";
                cookies.Add(newCookie);
                newCookie = new Cookie("reg_fb_ref", "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin%2Fidentify%3Fctx%3Drecover");
                newCookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";
                coo += "reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F;reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin%2Fidentify%3Fctx%3Drecover;";


                cookies.Add(newCookie);

                name = cookieString[4].Substring(10, cookieString[4].LastIndexOf("=") - 10).TrimStart();
                value = cookieString[4].Substring(cookieString[4].IndexOf("=") + 1).TrimEnd(';');
                cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
                cookie.Domain = "www.facebook.com";
                cookies.Add(cookie);
                coo += name + "=" + value + ";";
                coo+= "highContrastMode=0;wd=1920x976;";

                nameValuePairs = new NameValueCollection();
                nameValuePairs.Add("__user", "0");
                nameValuePairs.Add("__a", "1");
                nameValuePairs.Add("__dyn", "7w86i");
                nameValuePairs.Add("__req", "1");
                nameValuePairs.Add("fb_dtsg", "AQDdK6At");
                nameValuePairs.Add("q", "Miny1~66~%22%3A~%22%3A%22~%2C%22~%22%2C%22~.~null~0~%22%2C%7B%22~script_path_change~%5D%2C%5B%22~%22%3A%5B~time_spent~1~user~page_id~97dbjl~trigger~time~posts~%22%3A%5B%5B%22~source_path~WebRecoverInitiateController~source_token~01afab33~dest_path~dest_token~navigation~cause~%22%7D%2C~29183~time_spent_bit_array~tos_id~start_time~tos_array~%2C~%5D%2C%22~tos_len~tos_seq~tos_cum~%7D%2C~noxdt2~ods~%3A~ms~qa~www~15~4~%5B%7B%22~1375031063833~unload~1375031063~1053788547~31~21~%5D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22~1375031093606~load~1375031093~11~9597~bits~js_initialized~%5D%7D%2C~10599~%5D%5D%7D%5D~1MJxCzKxLzMxEzNw1NyOPEDQxRzSxTzUwByVwByWwByXx1OYZF-D_xLz1ww1Py1xG1Q1yC1z1Aw1Ry1BwIy1Cw1S1DZ1TJxCzKx1EzMx1F1G1HAHA1IA1JzNw1UyOPEDQwBySwByUxRzVxTzWwByXx1VY1KF-D_x1Ez1ww1Wy1xG1K1yC1z1Aw1Xy1BwCy1Cw1L1D1YF1F1G1HAHA1IA1JDHA1ZA1-GI1_2w2x");  
                nameValuePairs.Add("ts", "1375031104207");
                nameValuePairs.Add("ph", "V3");     
                nameValuePairs.Add("miny_encode_ms", "6");

                client = new WebClient();
                client.Headers.Add("set-cookie", coo);
                response = client.UploadValues("https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bz", nameValuePairs);
                chars = new char[response.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
                {
                    chars[i] = Convert.ToChar(response[i]);
                }
                s = new string(chars);


                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate");


                //req.Headers.Add("set-cookie", cookie);
                req.Host = "www.facebook.com";
                req.CookieContainer = cookies;
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0";
                req.KeepAlive = true;
                resp = req.GetResponse();
                streamReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                s = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                if (s.Contains("sometext"))   //example text to look for in the response
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }


        }
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare exactly what data you are sending compared to when doing it in a browser manually.
I would especially inspect the header fields of the HTTP request.

Comment: That is what I'm doing. I made my requests while checking the headers and then attaching the response headers to my next request. I'm examining headers though TemperData in firefox. Would it help you if I post my code for you?

Comment: I have added the code to my original post. I basically qrote a method which takes a number as input and then query against it on facebook and return true if the 'sometext' criteria is met and if I get captcha I get the captcha image read it and then put the captcha into the file from where my program reads it and passes to facebook. And then I again send the request with the captcha. I know the code is too bloated. But right now I'm not looking to write a complete application, I'm just doing a PoC for now for my assignment.